# SQL Server - check more than 1 value in where condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, subquery

```
SELECT * 
FROM table1
WHERE (@Id IS NULL
   OR (a.ID = @Id)
   OR (SELECT * FROM Table2 WHERE TestID = @Id) // How to check multiple values here
```

The above query works fine when `TestID` has single record. But when more than 1 record present in `TestID` column, I am trying to implement and not got exact solution.

How to confirm `@Id` value present in `TestId` column?

Could you please assist me on this? Thank you

Comment: What do you mean "confirm @Id value present in TestId field"? Are you storing multiple values in a delimited list or something?

Comment: "The above query works fine". I doubt that; `a.ID`: what is `a`? `OR (SELECT * FROM Table2 WHERE TestID = @Id)` is not a boolean expression. I think you oversimplified your query. Please also add some sample data to show what you want to accomplish

Comment: And why did you tag `linq`?

Comment: @HoneyBadger, For my point of view, People have good knowledge in `linq` will have good query knowledge which helps to resolve the problem.

Comment: That is not what tags are for

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you  need *exists*

```
or exists (
  SELECT * FROM Table2 WHERE TestID = @Id
)
```

Comment: Actually, I have to check for reverse condition, that is need to confirm `@Id` present in `TestId` field. Could you please assist me on this. Thanks

Comment: what you mean by reverse condition, this does exactly that, ie, checks if `@id` is the value of `TestId` column for any row. If that's not what you mean you need to update your question with a clearer description.

Answer (score 0):

Use `top 1` before `* from` this way you will always get a single row in case there are multiple rows for the same `@ID`.

```
SELECT top 1 * FROM Table2 WHERE TestID = @Id
```

Though I am not sure how this line works in `where` clause as it does not return any `boolean`